# How to add sourceMappingURL to .js file

Tags: coffeescript

I use CoffeeScript Redux zu generate .js and .js.map files. But coffee does not add the "sourceMappingURL" to the js file.

CoffeeScript 1.6.2 does this via the -m param. How can i make CoffeScript 2.0 to link the .map file?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux/blob/master/src/command.coffee#L257), this should happen if you pass `--source-map-file`. If it does not, this is probably a bug.